# Intento buscar una identificación tipo string repetida en un array en c#, tengo una clase vendedor que tiene identificacion, nombre, etc

Tags: c#

Cuando registro a los vendedores necesito verificar que no se repita la identificacion.

`Vendedores[] arrVendedores = new Vendedores[20];`

Metodo para guardar al vendedor

```
       {
           for(int i = 0; i < arrVendedores.Length; i++)
           {
               arrVendedores[contVend] = new Vendedores(id, nom, ape1, ape2, nac, gen, ing);
           }

           contVend++;
           MessageBox.Show("Datos guardados correctamente ", "ALERTA");
       }
```

Metodo para buscar lo cual me tira error

```
public bool idVend(string idVe)
    {
        bool vali = true;
        
        if (contVend > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < contVend; i++)
            {
                if (arrVendedores[i].Identificacion == idVe)
                {
                    vali = false;
                }
            }
        }

        return vali;
    }
```

Comment: Hola Chris, me puedes decir si la respuesta dada te fue útil, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar **Linq** para ver si ese dato ya existe:

```
public bool ExisteVendedor(string idVendedor)
{
    bool existe = false;
    
    var cont = (from v in arrVendedores
                where v.idVendedor == idVendedor
                select v).Count();

    return cont > 0;
}
```

Esta función ejecuta una consulta **Linq**, la cual va a recorrer todos los elementos del arreglo seleccionando los que tienen el mismo **idVendedor**. Una vez que se tengan todos los elementos que tienen el mismo **idVendedor**, se aplica el **operador Count**, el cual va a devolvernos el total de elementos que coinciden con el **idVendedor** pasado como parámetro a la función.

Por ultimo si **cont > 0**, la función retorna **true**, lo cual quiere decir que ya ese vendedor fue insertado, caso contrario retorna **false**, ya que ese vendedor aun no se ha insertado.

Para usar la funcion hacemos:

```
if (ExisteVendedor(idVendedor))
{
   //Insertamos el vendedor
}
else
{
   //Avisamos al usuario de que ese vendedor ya fue insertado.
}
```

Para usar **Linq** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Linq;
```